# How do I add a Confirm Order button in Commerce Checkout?

Tags: commerce

Using Commerce Kickstart 2

With the default checkout, the payment is taken on the Review page. Then the next page (Payment) processes with the merchant (in our case Authorize.Net).

Then there is a Confirmation Page... and the only pane on that page is Express Checkout Review and confirm' (does that refer to Paypal?).

I guess I'm expecting to a see a 'Confirm Your Order' button of some kind, but it never appears. Basically, the order is processed and goes immediately to 'Completed'.

How do I get that Confirmation page to appear?

Customers will expect to see a Confirm Order page -after- they have entered their payment... rather than going -immediately- to 'Completed'.

Comment: i'm wondering the same thing here.

Comment: @TopTomato: This may not be helpful, but if you aren't too far along, I would -strongly- suggest you look at another solution besides Commerce---it's not ready for prime time IMO. Otherwise: it's been a while since I worked on this site, but the Express Checkout -is- part of PayPal Express and that is what confused me. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting at the website.com/admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules address, which will bring you to settings page where you are seeing "Express Checkout" options, which to my knowledge is not a PayPal feature and unfortunately is just shares the same name as their Express Payment Processor.

Next you want want to create a checkout rule, which will give you more control over the order process, which can be found at website.com/admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules

This process might start to get difficult, but essentially you want to create a Rule that will trigger a more detailed confirmation page, which can probably handled numerous ways and probably out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Express Checkout option is part of the Commerce Paypal Express checkout module. I say that because the machine name of the pane is 'paypal_ec'.

Comment: thanks Kames but i believe it is part of PayPal Express. it's shoddy in that there is a link to a confirm pane even it PayPal isn't being used.